# xcode NSURLConnection NSMutableData appendData only works for certain types of content

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have created a class for fetching server-side data in my iOS-App, based on NSURLConnection, forwarding the fetched data to a delegate for processing.

When downloading text/json this works perfectly.

I am now expanding to fetch some png-images and can't get the data through.

I have located that it breaks in the didReceiveData-call, where [receivedData appendData:data] do not do anything for the received image-data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Append the new data to receivedData.
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

I get data into this method (NSData >0 bytes), but calling [receivedData appendData:data] do not change the size of receivedData (Still 0 bytes).

As this works perfectly with text and not with image-data I believe it has something to do with characterset or encoding to do, but cannot find anything on this.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update** with requested code-samples:

In the method that makes the call:

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    // Also tried with no change in behaviour
    // receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

My `didReceiveResponse`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [receivedData setLength:0];
}
```

---

**Another UPDATE**

Turns out the problem bois down to concurrency as I fire three instances of the class simultaniously to fetch three files asynchroniously. The problem is that the first releases `receivedData` when finishing ruining the response from the two other instances.

How do I make sure that each instance of the class has their own `receivedData` to play with?

---

**Final Notes**
Using a dictionary of MutableArrays for the retreived data solves the concurrency-problem.

It also seems like defining the MutableArray as a private property of the class creates one array for each instance.

```
@interface MyClass(){
    @private NSMutableData * receivedData;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that `receivedData` is simply `nil`.

Comment: Plz show us the "-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
" method in your app.

Comment: The `connection didReceiveResponse` simply reset the receivedData by calling `[receivedData setLength:0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever initialize `receivedData`?

Something like this would do it:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(!receivedData)
    {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

An even faster approach is to initialize it right before you kick off the actual request (so that it's not being checked every time data is received).

also remember to nil `receivedData` when your request is completed and you are done extracting it so that it will be ready to go for the next request.

---

**Here's one solution for concurrent requests:**

Instead of a single NSMutableData property, create an NSMutableDictionary so that you can hang on to multiple instances at once.

`NSMutableDictionary *receivedData`

Now, once you put together your NSURLConnection (let's call it `urlConnection`), you can create a new unique data object and put it in your dictionary. You should be able to use the string description of the connection as your unique key.

```
if(!receivedData)
  receivedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

NSMutableData *dataObject = [NSMutableData data];
[receivedData setObject:dataObject forKey:[urlConnection description]];
```

Now you can do this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  NSMutableData *currentData = (NSMutableData*)[receivedData objectForKey:[connection description]];
  [currentData.appendData:data];
}
```

Once your connection has completed, remember to call `removeObjectForKey` to get rid of data objects once they are no longer needed.

Comment: Yep. It is initialized further up in the code, and is set prior to adding data.

Comment: After running even more detailed analysis on the problem the problem seems to be concurrency and a static (per-class) receivedData.
As the process fires three instances of the file-downloading to get the three files the first one to finish sets `receivedData = nil` for cleanup before the latter finishes.

Comment: So I guess the question then is: How do I make sure that `receivedData` is kept distinct for each instance of my responseClass?

Comment: I didn't realize you had multiple connections running at once. Updating my answer with a solution you can implement easily.

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that any "global variable" in a class is shared among the instances of that class? (Which is a bit counter-intuitive from other languages and platfoms I've been working with).

Comment: Moving the definition of `receivedData` to the interface (Extended in the class implementation as follows also seems to solve the problem.

    @interface APIBase(){
        @private NSMutableData * receivedData;
    }

Comment: Oh, looks like I misunderstood again. If each of your requests is initiated and handled by a completely different instance of a class, you only need to handle one request within the class (as you did). The second code example I posted is for a single class instance kicking off and handling multiple requests. If your data object is an ivar/property, you should not have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working workaround, which is sending the data base64 encoded in a JSON-response to the device and decode it before using the files locally on the device.

This also proves quite helpful in that it enables transfering the three files needed in one request.